# Calculate (or look up) fundamental financial quantities for stocks

Tags: python, finance

I've seen a number of ways to script code (for example, in python: [ystockquote](http://goldb.org/ystockquote.html)) that returns the stock price (or the historical closing prices) of a particular stock. Is there a way of scripting the information for calculating various fundamental quantities: [Enterprise Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_value), EBITDA (I know this is included in that python link), Free-cash-flow...etc.

I'm asking whether there is a command-line tool that can be pinged to return this kind of information (or enough of the relevant information to do the calculation oneself)? Something like a repository for earnings statements/debt/cash flow/taxes.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I think it is more difficult to find _where_ you can get this information than _how_ can you query it using Python. I see in Wikipedia article you have posted that EV isn't publicly traded and is disclosed when it is out of date. For instance, there are some modules for data mining like [pattern.web](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web) or [mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/), which can be used to build a command-line tool for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

JBW,

You can do this in multiple steps but you will have to invest some time to use the API and identify the financial data from the companies.

1) Identify company's CIK
2) Download XBRL file from SEC FTP
3) Use the numbers provided to compute the metric you are looking for
3*) Some companies will already contain those values in the XML

FTP Info : http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/ftpusers.htm
XBRL Spec: http://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/nsarxml1_d.htm

I hope this helps.

Vladimir